# How would I allow multiple users in an array to have separate access to a variable?

Tags: java

I understand the title is quite confusing so I'll clarify here.

The following is an extremely simple bank class I slapped together that takes the users name and balance and has deposit and withdraw classes.

```
public class Bank {

String user;
int balance = 0;
int pin;

public void setup (String n,int p)
{
    user = n;
    pin = p;
}

public void withdraw (int amount)
{
    balance -= amount;
}

public void deposit (int amount)
{
    balance += amount;
}

public String toString ()
{
    return String.format("User: %s\nBalance: %s",user,balance);
}
}
```

Now. Here is my qualm. The following is another simple class I made to make use of the Bank class. I've tried HashMaps, Arrays and I'm sure I'm just missing a basic principle. This isn't for a class I would just like to know how to do the following:

I want to be able to create different users (I'm sure I'd have to use (like I have) a HashMap or ArrayList) and have EACH user have separate access to the balance variable, so when one person, lets say person X with pin 1234 withdraws funds, ONLY their funds are withdrawn.

I know I can just use a HashMap and set it up like

```
 HashMap <String, Integer> HM = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
 HM.put("User",0)
```

where user is the name and 0 is the balance.
I can easily update different users balances, but this seems counterintuitive.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class BankDriver {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    boolean quit = false;
    Bank b = new Bank ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("1: Create account\2: Quit");
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                b.setup("Name",1234);
                System.out.println(b.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }

    }while(!quit);
    System.out.println("Exiting.");
}
}
```

How would YOU accomplish this?

AGAIN. I know I can do it in different ways, but I was curious if I could accomplish it this way.

Comment: `HashMap<String,Account>`?  I think the think you're calling `Bank` is really one account in a bank.

Comment: You need to create class `User` with all banking properties and then add `List<User>` to `Bank`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object oriented design that you are using is not very good for what you are trying to achieve. If you want to have access for each client of the bank, you should create a `Client` class (or Account) with its getters and setters like this:

Also, I changed your `integers` to `doubles`

```
public class Client{
    public int pin;
    public String name;
    public double amount;
    public Client(String name, double amount, int pin){
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getPin(){
        return pin;
    }

    public void changePin(int newPin){
        this.pin = newPin;
    }
    public void withdraw (double amount)
    {
        this.amount -= amount;
    }

    public void deposit (double amount)
    {
        this.amount  += _amount;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("User: %s\nBalance: %s",this.name,this.amount);
    }
}
```

Now, from your `void()` you can create all the Clients that you want in any specific data structure. I'll give you an example using a `HashMap`

```
 HashMap <String, Client> HM = new HashMap <String, Client>();
 HM.put("Uri D. Charles", new Client("Uri D. Charles", 100.00, 1234));
 HM.put("Luis Lavieri", new Client("Luis Lavieri", 2000.00, 1234));
```

After that you can manipulate the data structure as you prefer to access that data. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Doubles do not mix well with currency.  Integers aren't great either, but at least they aren't lossy.  `BigDecimal`, or even better the [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) library, is the right way to represent money in an application.  For a toy application you probably don't need to go overboard about it, but floating point precision is definitely undesirable.

Comment: Also the `_variable` pattern your using isn't a common Java idiom.  I suppose it's not wrong, but it's unusual.  Use `this.variable = variable` to assign a local variable to an instance variable of the same name.

Comment: The big decimal kind of broke things, as there are incompatible types.

Comment: Change it to double. It was a suggestion. but for practice double is enough. I'll change my example

Comment: HOWEVER. Previously, everything did make excellent sense. There were issues with 'security' as the user needed to just type in the name of the person and that's it to edit the balances. But nevertheless it DID work. Now I have to figure out how to fix these BigDecimal bugs.

Comment: Cool. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a getter methods for name and pin.

You can create an ArrayList of Bank object and add the bank object to the  arraylist each time a user created an account.

Then when the user want to withdraw you then ask them there name and pin and then loop the arraylist while comparing the pin and name of the bank object of the arraylist and the person name and pin that just entered.

If the object was found you can then ask the user how much money to withdraw and call the widraw method.

Comment: about the getters, I plan to but l just rushed this so I could ask my question. I feel like I've tried this and failed. I'll try again using this method.